# How to push to object in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I know I'm probably overlooking something obvious, but when trying to push to an existing object, nothing happens. It will log up to "Makes it here".

```
const storeData = async (todo) => {
  try {
    const getCurrentTodos = await AsyncStorage.getItem('todos');
    let currentTodos = JSON.parse(getCurrentTodos);

    if(currentTodos) {
      currentTodos = [];
    }

    console.log('Makes it here', currentTodos)
    currentTodos.push(todo);
    console.log('Does not make it here', currentTodos)
  } catch(e) {
    // save error
  }

  console.log('Makes it here.')
}
```

This is the currentTodos obj

```
Object {
  "description": "none",
  "title": "Test 1",
}
```

This is the todo obj

```
Object {
  "description": "none",
  "title": "Test 2",
}
```

Comment: you are trying to push object to object. not possible.. currentTodos should be an array

Comment: See I thought that, but AsyncStorage says it requires object, and various example code showed pushing in this way. I'll try changing it to array and see if AsyncStorage will still work.

Comment: AsyncStorage is an key-value storage system.. value can be anything-string, number ,object, array etc. it gets store as string, hence it doesnt matter.

Comment: You're right, I misread it, thank you! I got it working now.